# how to stop the shaking effect on my homepage

Tags: css, html

This is my http://iradionortheast.com/
Password: ireland

Please check the attachment for better understanding.

http://uploadpie.com/ASgk7

This part of my website on my homepage, is giving a shaking effect when I hover over it.

Please help me ASAP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what causes the "shaking effect" :

```
#main section:hover
```

At line 77 in [this file](http://iradionortheast.com/?sccss=1&ver=4.3.1)

So whenever you hover the section, the width changes and you are not hovering the section anymore, and this goes on..